# Is it valid to add the same element as a child to two different parent elements in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose I have some HTML as so,

```
<div id="first"></div>
<div id="second"></div>
```

and using JavaScript and JQuery I attempt to do the following

```
var $child = $("<span id='child'>Hello</span>");

$("#first").append($child);
$("#second").append($child);
```

Will I have two copies of the child node, or will I have two references to the *same* child node?

**Update**

I realise that my example creation of a child element is a bit wrong. Perhaps

```
var $child = $("<span/>").text("Hello");
```

is a bit more correct.

Answer (score 4):

Child appended in the `#first` element will get moved to `#second` element leaving `#first` element empty. You can use `clone()` to insert a copy of the child element.

However, there should not be multiple elements with the same ID in DOM, so please change `ID` to `Class` for the `child element`